# Permission issue when deploying a new model version in the training script in GCP AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to automate the model deployment in GCP AI Platform. I.e., after a model is trained successfully, I package and upload the model and source package to GCS, and deploy it as a new version and set as default. I have this at the end of my training script. I need this because the model retrains periodically.

In the training script, the packaging and uploading (calling `gsutil` with `subprocess`) worked fine but I ran into permission issues when trying to deploy a new version. I've tried to

- call `gcloud ai-platform` with `subprocess`
- call `discovery.build('ml', 'v1').projects().models().versions().create()` from `googlecloudapis` directly
- invoke a Cloud Function that does the above

Any way I receive the error

```
ResponseError: status=[403], code=[Forbidden], message=[Request had insufficient authentication scopes.]
```

I've added enough permissions to the service account for AI Platform (`service-xxxxxxxxx@cloud-ml.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`, Google Cloud ML Engine Service Agent), but it didn't work.

It seems inside the training instances a different account is used. `discovery.build('ml', 'v1')._http.credentials._service_account` returns `default` instead of an email.

Before I go on to use Cloud Function to monitor the export from the training script, I'd like to ask if I missed anything or if there're any other options?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried creation of model via gcloud command? https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models#service-account

Answer (score 0):

I look into service account permissions and saw Cloud ML Engine Admin, Developer and Viewer.

Some sample code below:

[image]

From [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/oauth2/service_account.py)

```
    Usually, you'll create these credentials with one of the helper
    constructors. To create credentials using a Google service account
    private key JSON file::
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            'service-account.json')
    Or if you already have the service account file loaded::
        service_account_info = json.load(open('service_account.json'))
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
            service_account_info)
    Both helper methods pass on arguments to the constructor, so you can
    specify additional scopes and a subject if necessary::
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            'service-account.json',
            scopes=['email'],
            subject='user@example.com')
```

From [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ml-on-gcp/blob/master/tutorials/tensorflow/mlflow_gcp/trainer/model_deployment.py)

```
def get_client(service_account_json):
    """Returns an authorized API client by discovering the Healthcare API and
    creating a service object using the service account credentials JSON."""
    api_scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        service_account_json)
    scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(api_scopes)

    return discovery.build(
        'ml',
        'v1',        
        credentials=scoped_credentials)
```

Comment: I'm afraid this is not helpful. I know how to manage service account and permission. I've tried to give Owner to most of service accounts in the project but still the same error. In the training script I can access bigquery but not cloud functions or AI platform deploy.

Comment: I suspect the container image for runtime 1.14 uses a special service account that's not exposed or documented.